# Package com.google.zxing missing in Zxing barcode library for Android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have downloaded the Zxing Barcode Scanner code for Android, but I can't find the package *com.google.zxing* in the source code.  I think there's a missing library or JAR file for the project. Can anybody help me find that package?

These are the unresolved imports:

```
  import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
  import com.google.zxing.Result;
  import com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType;
  import com.google.zxing.ResultPoint;
```

Comment: @Rana.S, did you find an answer? Why not share it and accept that.

Comment: Readers are encouraged to upvote, comment any solutions that are helpful.  Contributors will state their success in an **Answer** with a instructions, procedure code to advance future problem solvers

Answer (score 15):

The classes you are looking for are in the [core](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing.) module.

Comment: so the core file generated with appache ant has to be added as external jar file even for the new project

Comment: @png  If you were successful, please consider either creating your own answer or adding to the above existing answer stating success and the procedure \ steps required.

Answer (score 7):

What a headache to see the classes in the download.zip's core folder but there is no "core.jar", so here's where to get that jar file...

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing

1. Under "Just Need a Jar", click the "Maven release repository" link.
2. [Click "core/"](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/)
3. Click on the Zxing version you downloaded.
   (Though mine is 4.7.5  (shown on zip folder name) it worked with version [3.2.1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.1/)
4. Click on core-x.x.x.jar to download. (x's are version number)

I put that core.jar where the Zxing project folder is, inside core folder so I wouldn't lose it.

After that, (if using Eclipse)

1. Right click CaptureActivity project -> Build Path -> Configure Build
   Path
2. (Left Side Select) Java Build Path
3. Libraries tab
4. Add External JARs...
5. Select the core-x.x.x.jar previously downloaded
6. Click OK

This took all those missing errors away for me, but left errors in switch statements that I read needs to be changed to if/else statements, but that's for another topic.

Comment: @dataicc  For the final errors in switch statements, is there a link that illuminates and resolves said errors?

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me. I use Intellij Idea, litte bit different for adding jar, but generally the same.